# Lie Algebra connections to other fields

Tags: lie-algebras

I just started learning about lie algebra, really the very basics. Definition and motivation mostly. And clearly it's a field which is very motivated by differential geometry.
I was wondering what connections there are to other fields, such as Algebraic topology, Algebraic geometry, number theory or category theory.

Comment: Lie groups are fascinating animals in the algebraic topologist's biosphere and Lie algebras are a vital tool in understanding them.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1322206/96384. Even more related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/58696/27465